# Create an Availability calendar/table in Views

Tags: views, datetime

I am trying to create a calendar table in Views to display availability states for multiple product rows, e.g. for a car rental site.
I have spent the evening researching modules that might be suitable, namely availability calendars (which I am familiar with) and a bunch of views plugins, even considered modifying rooms or uc_hotel modules to suit.. I haven't found anything that fits the bill exactly, but that's what I expected, so I'm looking for some recommendations or a solution. I have attached an illustration of what I am trying to achieve. Any help or pointers much appreciated.

[image: Availability calendar table]

Comment: Is there a JavaScript library that does this now?

Comment: I don't know.  I'll look around.  If you find one, reply with the link to the library, and I can show you how to do it.  Otherwise, you'll need to write it from scratch.

Answer (score 1):

An update.. in the end I decided against using views, and used a library called dhtmlx scheduler timeline. It's turned out to meet the requirements spot on, and wasn't too difficult to wrangle into Drupal..
[image: dhtmlx scheduler]

Answer (score 0):

If you're still interested in an answer, you could use the [Views Table Group](https://www.drupal.org/project/tablegroup) module (dates as columns and product names as rows) and with the [Views Conditional](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_conditional) or [Views PHP](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_php) module and/or a custom theme you could choose the style for the cell.

Comment: Thanks I will see what I can do with it. Biggest challenge I'm facing is the calendar functionality.